# In Django REST framework's filtering, What "purchaser__username=username" mean

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm studying to using Django Rest framework in my Project, but I'm confuse with this code

```
    serializer_class = PurchaseSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Optionally restricts the returned purchases to a given user,
        by filtering against a `username` query parameter in the URL.
        """
        queryset = Purchase.objects.all()
        username = self.request.query_params.get('username')
        if username is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(purchaser__username=username)
        return queryset
```

What does `purchaser__username=username` mean in this code ? It quite confusing me for time now.

Answer (score 0):

The double underscore in a queryset filter often means you are following some kind of relationship between different models.

In this case, you have a model Purchase, and that model has a field 'purchaser'. The 'purchaser' field will likely be a many-to-one link to another model such as User (because Purchases can have one purchaser, but a User may make many purchases). The User model has a field 'username', probably a simple string.

So the queryset.filter is saying, get all instances of the Purchase model that refer to a particular User in the purchaser field. To tell which particular User, match the User's 'username' field (purchaser__username) to the username string from the URL querystring (ie, get_queryset.html?username=fred123)